# nontrivial cube root of unity

Tags: finite-fields, roots-of-unity

Hi,

I have a finite field Fp with p = 11 mod(12) and I am trying to get the third nontrivial root of unity in Fp^2 = Fp^2[x]/(x^2+1). So, i need x where x^3=1.

Somehow I came into a source saying that it would be:
(p-1)/2 + (3^((p+1)/4)) mod(p))*i where i^2=-1.
But it seems not to be correct:
Any idea?

Comment: Presumably you mean $F_{p^2}[x]/(x^2+1)$?

Comment: Yes. I meant that!

Comment: You can edit your question - the "edit" button is right underneath the tags. Also, you mean "nontrivial cube root of unity", not "third nontrivial root of unity", because every element of a finite field other than 0 and 1 is a nontrivial root of unity.

Comment: Also, I'm afraid that your question is not at the right level for MO, but there are many other sites where your question would be better suited. See http://mathoverflow.net/faq#whatnot.

Comment: probably you are right. I am not a mathematician so am not quite familiar with the terminology. So I need sigma where sigma^3=1 in Fp^2[x]/(x^2+1).

Comment: Actually, I am stuck with this for weeks and I would appreciate a help! Or maybe some reference at least.

Comment: Right. However, the polynomial $x^2+1$ already has its roots in $F_{p^2}$, so $F_{p^2}[x]/(x^2+1)$ cannot be a finite field.

Comment: @Niti: do ask in math.stackexchange.com

Comment: no actually (x^2+1) is irreducible in F_p for p = 3 mod(4).

Comment: But even though it is irreducible over $F_p$ when $p\equiv 3\bmod 4$, it will still split in $F_{p^2}$.

Comment: Still a problem, though. There is already a square root of -1 in the quadratic extension of the prime field (p is congruent to 3 mod 4, so its square is congruent to 1 mod 4, and therefore this extension has a cyclic multiplicative group of order divisible by 4). So the first suggestion is probably wrong, and instead the quadratic extension is supposed to be generated over the prime field by the square root of -1? That at least makes sense ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is about imitating the formula for a complex cube root of unity. Write p as 12k - 1. The real issue is only why 3 to the power 3k should act as square root of 3 in this field. Square it and apply Fermat's little theorem to see why. (There is a missing factor 2 in the formula you gave.)

Comment: Hi Charles, where exactly do you think the 2 is missing?

Comment: Please write down the formula for a complex cube root of unity.

Comment: lets say z^3=1. 
Then z in complex (Re{z} + i* Im{z}): 
Re{z} = (p-1)/2, 
Im{z} = 3^((p+1)/4) mod(p)

Comment: Sigh. Like in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity#Examples. The formula you are proposing mimics that formula, but it is *all* over the factor 2. Anyway I guess I gave the wrong reason about the square root of 3, since quadratic reciprocity should enter. But like everyone said, MO is the wrong forum; and your statement had a couple of errors also.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it now. You are my hero.

Anyway I am surprised why all of you get so uppset. I made some errors but... I am just trying to learn.